# How to calculate empirical probability with a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider I have a data frame, `df` for which we have to calculate the empirical probability for each variable, possibly also as a data frame with an equal number of rows and observations.

(I'll use `cluster::flower` for example.)

```
> flower[0:2]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6       V7    V8
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <ord> <ord> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0     1     1     4     3     15       25    15
 2 1     0     0     2     1     3       150    50
```

I have an empirical probability function.

```
emp_prob = function(x)
{
   y = table(x)/length(x)
   return(y)
}
```

How do I apply it to all the columns, and then replace all values in the data frame with their empirical probabilities? So far, I'm using `apply()` to apply it to all columns but don't know what's next.

Comment: You cannot put the distributions back into a data frame because you cannot guarantee that they will be of equal length or contain the same categories. For example, `x <- c(12, 5, 17, 3, 3, 15, 5, 1, 7, 9)` produces a table with 8 categories, 1, (no 2), 3, (no 4), 5, (no 6), 7, (no 8), 9, (no 10 or 11), 12, (no 13 or 14), 15, (no 16), 17. The next column will not necessarily contain the same categories or the same number of categories. You should use `sapply` and create a list.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to solve it using dplyr verbs. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually.

Here's a reprex in case someone stumbles upon it again.

```r
library(tidyverse)
flower_cat = cluster::flower[,1:6]
flower_complete = flower_cat %>% 
   group_by(V1) %>% 
   mutate(V1.count = n()) %>% 
   mutate(V1.freq = V1.count/nrow(flower_cat)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(V2) %>% 
   mutate(V2.count = n()) %>% 
   mutate(V2.freq = V2.count/nrow(flower_cat)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(V3) %>% 
   mutate(V3.count = n()) %>% 
   mutate(V3.freq = V3.count/nrow(flower_cat)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(V4) %>% 
   mutate(V4.count = n()) %>% 
   mutate(V4.freq = V4.count/nrow(flower_cat)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(V5) %>% 
   mutate(V5.count = n()) %>% 
   mutate(V5.freq = V5.count/nrow(flower_cat)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(V6) %>% 
   mutate(V6.count = n()) %>% 
   mutate(V6.freq = V6.count/nrow(flower_cat)) %>% 
   ungroup()
flower_complete
#> # A tibble: 18 × 18
#>    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V1.count V1.freq V2.count V2.freq
#>    <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <ord> <ord>    <int>   <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>
#>  1 0     1     1     4     3     15           8   0.444       10   0.556
#>  2 1     0     0     2     1     3           10   0.556        8   0.444
#>  3 0     1     0     3     3     1            8   0.444       10   0.556
#>  4 0     0     1     4     2     16           8   0.444        8   0.444
#>  5 0     1     0     5     2     2            8   0.444       10   0.556
#>  6 0     1     0     4     3     12           8   0.444       10   0.556
#>  7 0     0     0     4     3     13           8   0.444        8   0.444
#>  8 0     0     1     2     2     7            8   0.444        8   0.444
#>  9 1     1     0     3     1     4           10   0.556       10   0.556
#> 10 1     1     0     5     2     14          10   0.556       10   0.556
#> 11 1     1     1     5     3     8           10   0.556       10   0.556
#> 12 1     1     1     1     2     9           10   0.556       10   0.556
#> 13 1     1     0     1     2     6           10   0.556       10   0.556
#> 14 1     1     1     4     2     11          10   0.556       10   0.556
#> 15 1     0     0     3     2     10          10   0.556        8   0.444
#> 16 1     0     0     4     2     18          10   0.556        8   0.444
#> 17 1     0     0     2     2     17          10   0.556        8   0.444
#> 18 0     0     1     2     1     5            8   0.444        8   0.444
#> # … with 8 more variables: V3.count <int>, V3.freq <dbl>, V4.count <int>,
#> #   V4.freq <dbl>, V5.count <int>, V5.freq <dbl>, V6.count <int>, V6.freq <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>